# Accessing Webservice by Android - KSOAP2

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm creating an Android app and I have to connect with the web service from my company to do the login system, I'm using 3.3.0 KSOAP2 lib.

The path of my WS is such as: http://www.dominio.com/servicos/ws.asmx

My problem happens:

```
09-04 10:57:52.835: W/System.err(19717): 
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 
'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
http://www.dominio.com/servicos/ObterIdentificadorLoja.'
faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@428e60d0
```

Variables stored for the connection:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://www.dominio.com/servicos/ws.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private String TAG = "LOGAR";
```

My WSDL is:

```
<wsdl:operation name="ObterIdentificadorLoja">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja" style="document"/>
```

Source .Java code full:

```
package com.testes.infovendas;

//Imports
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

//KSOAP2 -- Lib de conexão Webservice SOAP
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

//Adicionais
import com.testes.infovendas.R;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InfoVendas extends ActionBarActivity {

//Variáveis
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private final String URL = "http://www.dominio.com/servicos/ws.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "ObterIdentificadorLoja";
private String TAG = "ASSYNC";
private static String cnpj_cpf_codclie, codloja, seguranca, identificadorloja;
Button b;
TextView tv;
EditText et1,et2,et3,et4;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    //Identificando cada campo e função
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCodloja);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCPF);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUser);
    et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPass);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_informa);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    //Listener para quando clicar no botão Enviar
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Se todos os campos forem preenchidos, será retomado o login
            if (et1.getText().length() != 0 && et1.getText().toString() != "" || 
                    et2.getText().length() != 0 && et2.getText().toString() != "" || 
                    et3.getText().length() != 0 && et3.getText().toString() != "" || 
                    et4.getText().length() != 0 && et4.getText().toString() != "") {

                //Pega todas as informações escritas nos campos e adiciona em suas respectivas variáveis para uso do WS
                codloja = et1.getText().toString();
                cnpj_cpf_codclie = et2.getText().toString();
                seguranca = "chavesecreta";

                AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                task.execute();

            } 
            //Se não for preenchido todos os campos, será retornado um TextView apenas informado para informar corretamente
            else {
                tv.setText("Por favor, insira todos os dados.");
            }
        }
    });
}

//Classe AsyncCallWS
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    //Retorna como null o valor do Identificador
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        getIdentificador(cnpj_cpf_codclie, codloja, seguranca);
        return null;
    }

    //Mensagem e ação pós conclusão
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        tv.setText("identificador nº: " + identificadorloja + "  Conexão estabelecida. Realizando o login...");
    }

    //Mensagem ao clicar no botão Enviar
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        tv.setText("Estabelecendo conexão ao servidor...");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
    }

}

//Classe para obter os dados do Identificador
public void getIdentificador(String cnpj_cpf_codclie, String codloja, String seguranca) {
    //Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    //Property which holds input parameters
    PropertyInfo identificadorPI = new PropertyInfo();
    //Set Name
    identificadorPI.setName("identificadorloja");
    //Set Value
    identificadorPI.setValue(identificadorloja);
    //Set dataType
    identificadorPI.setType(double.class);
    //Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty(identificadorPI);
    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //Define identificadorloja como uma variável estática
        identificadorloja = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I need to access the "ObterIdentificadorLoja", only that always gives the error or the "header could not be recognized" or "Timeout" or "Reference is not set to an instance or object", and I tried several ways already ..

Where can I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

As your error is clearly stating, you have `SOAPAction` mismatch.

You are using `http://www.dominio.com/servicos/ObterIdentificadorLoja` while making SOAP request,

but, in your WSDL, you have `http://tempuri.org/ObterIdentificadorLoja`

Comment: I've changed my question! Check it out, @bhargavg!